# Redirect websockets to port?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, iptables, port-forwarding, socket

So, I've got a WebSocket server in C++, that is a completely stand-alone entity - handles header parsing, receiving, sending, all of it on its own, listening directly to the port.

Problem is, it needs to run on a server alongside Apache, and that's a bit of a problem. Now, there was a solution here to a similar issue involving mod_proxy, but I'm hoping I can intercept and redirect WebSocket communication before Apache even knows about it, possibly with iptables.

So the question is, is it possible to direct traffic bound for **chat**.mysite.net to a WebSocket server on, say, port 8080, while anything else headed to mysite.net proceeds as expected to Apache?

Comment: Not if they have the same IP address. You need HTTP header inspection to figure out if it's a websocket connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is actually pretty easy; just code the client to access the server at `ws://mysite.com:8080`. With all the touting of WebSockets being able to use port 80, I was quite surprised to learn it doesn't *need* to.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not possible with iptables because iptables doesn't speak/understand http protocol. Someone should write ip_conntrack_http so this could actually work (something similar as ftp conntrack thingie) ;-)
Till then you should probably use apache with mod_proxy or nginx.

Comment: I'm assuming that both servers are binded to the same IP address because otherwise this question doesn't make much sense (the answer would be too simple)